# how to iterate multimap backwards for unique key?

Tags: c++, iteration, multimap

I know how to do it forward:

```
for(auto it = mmap.begin(), end = mmap.end(); it != end; it = mmap.upper_bound(it->first))
```

but this doesn't work:

```
for(auto it = mmap.rbegin(), end = mmap.rend(); it != end; it = mmap.lower_bound(it->first))
```

giving:
`error: no match for 'operator=' in 'it = mmap.std::multimap<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::lower_bound<unsigned int, long int, std::less<unsigned int>, std::allocator<std::pair<const unsigned int, long int> > >((* & it.std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>::operator-><std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const unsigned int, long int> > >()->std::pair<const unsigned int, long int>::first))'`

Comment: Why are you using `upper_bound` and `lower_bound`?

Comment: @sftrabbit: First line is a way to iterate through unique keys in a multi-map.

Comment: @MM. Thanks - not seen this approach before.

Comment: @sftrabbit: upper_bound also doesn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `std::multimap::iterator` is not directly convertible to a `std::reverse_iterator`. You need to make the result of `std::lower_bound` the base iterator of `it`:

```
typedef ... multimap_type;
typedef std::reverse_iterator<multimap_type::iterator> reverse_iterator;

for (auto it = mmap.rbegin(),
          end = mmap.rend();
     it != end;
     it = reverse_iterator(mmap.lower_bound(it->first)))
{
  // ...
}
```

The expression `reverse_iterator(mmap.lower_bound(it->first))` will construct a `std::reverse_iterator` with the result of `lower_bound` as its base iterator.

Comment: @rsk82 I meant for that to be a placeholder for you to fill in. It should be the type of your multimap. For example, `std::multimap<int, int>`.

Comment: @rsk82 So it actually worked? Haha, I was expecting to do some bug fixing.